# JavaScript - Preventing octal conversion

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, octal

I'm taking a numerical input as an argument and was just trying to account for leading zeroes. But it seems javascript converts the number into octal before I can do anything to the number. The only way to work around it so far is if I pass the number as a string initially but I was hoping there'd be another way to convert it after it is passed? So far tried (using `017` which alerted me to the octal behaviour):

```
017.toString(10) // 15
parseInt(017,10) // 15
017 + "" //15
new Number(017) //15

new Number('017') //17
parseInt('017', 10) // 17
```

So given

```
function(numb) {

if (typeof numb === number) {
// remove leading zeroes and convert to decimal
}
else {
 // use parseInt
}

}
```

'use strict' also doesn't seem to solve this as some older posts have suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you taking a numerical input and have it *not* come out as string...?! A `Number` cannot have "leading zeros".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you take "numerical input", you should always definitely guaranteed have a string. There's no input method in this context that I know that returns a `Number`. Since you receive a string, `parseInt(.., 10)` will always be sufficient. `017` is only interpreted as octal if written literally as such in source code (or when missing the radix parameter to `parseInt`).
2. If for whatever bizarre reason you do end up with a decimal interpreted as octal and you want to reverse-convert the value back to a decimal, it's pretty simple: express the value in octal and re-interpret that as decimal:

   ```
   var oct = 017; // 15
   parseInt(oct.toString(8), 10) // 17
   ```

   Though because you probably won't know whether the input was or wasn't interpreted as octal originally, this isn't something you should have to do ever.

Comment: Sorry, by "numerical input" I just meant me passing the function a number like 017 as opposed to '017'. It's sort of just out of interest than a requirement as I was thinking of accounting for sending numbers that (perhaps by accident) have some leading zeroes.  Your second answer does help a lot too, I hadn't thought of doing that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If you write `017` in your source as an argument to a function, you *are* writing 15. Just in a different notation. Numbers don't have leading zeros. Write what you mean, don't make your code adapt to something you didn't actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript interprets all numbers beginning with a 0, and containing all octal numerals as octals - eg 017 would be an octal but 019 wouldn't be. If you want your number as a decimal then either 
1. Omit the leading 0. 
2. Carry on using parseInt().

The reason being is that JavaScript uses a few implicit conversions and it picks the most likely case based on the number. It was decided in JavaScript that a leading 0 was the signal that a number is an octal. If you need that leading 0 then you have to accept that rule and use parseInt().

[Source](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/octalsan.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you type numbers by hand to script then not use leading zeros (which implicity treat number as octal if it is valid octal - if not then treat it as decimal). If you have number as string then just use `+` operator to cast to (decimal) number.

```js
console.log(+"017")

if (021 < 019) console.log('Paradox');
```

The strict mode will not allow to use zero prefix

```js
'use strict'

if (021 < 019) console.log('Paradox');
```